# A Form element is breaking with an unset width

Tags: html, forms, button

I have been having troubles with styling a form.
I Created a site header, that header has 3 "buttons", that all of them are using one generic class, and one of their own in order to specify a width per button drop down container.

In the third one there is a drop down that has no width value set (tried with width auto as well), I'm placing a form, now there are two issue with it:

1. The submit button is breaking to a new line, from what i know (and aim for) if no width is set to the parent element, then the text input and the submit button should remain in the same line.
2. the submit button adds different margin to it's left in Firefox & Safari (Both on MAC)
   why is that, and is there a way to unify the appearance in all browsers ?

Picture: http://test-ground.tk/ex/snap.png

Live example: http://test-ground.tk/ex/example.html

Comment: post code here or setup a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I am having troubles posting the code as it's a pretty long one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the form that contains your search text and button add these styles (preferably in a class):

```
white-space:nowrap;
font-size:0px;
```

The `white-space:nowrap` keeps the INPUTs on one line and the `font-size:0px` gets rid of white space characters (by setting the size of them to 0).

The 'margin' you see in FF and Safari is actually a space character... browsers tend to have different ideas about how and when to render white space.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the code, do you have an idea why firefox now pushes the submit button down 1px down? with Safari the button & input are aligned perfectly

Comment: I don't see the search on http://test-ground.tk/ex/example.html anymore. FF and Safari render the buttons differently so that may be it. You could try setting height, line-height, vertical-align, padding, margins or maybe borders to change the look and positioning.

Comment: I see. That's odd. I had a look at your site again in FF. I was able to make it look a bit better with text-align:middle on your form elements.

Comment: yeah that solved it to 99% solution, I guess that i good enough, thanks again.